# Compact/simplify code where multipe conditions force repeating the code, and replace passing a multiple dict to be modified

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below:

In the code I have multiple branches/conditions and some repeated code(`process`).
I'm looking if is possible for a more compact version.

Also in the `process` function a defaultdict(mutable) is passed as an argument(to function process), which I don't like it, I'm trying to find a solution with no side effect that doesn't complicate the code.

```
# data  iterable
direct_cotainer  = defaultdict(set)

if config.a: #check a bool value in a config
  a = get_a() # get from a file or database - abstract -an iterable
  if not a: # 
     # log something
     return
  else:  # a has elements
   for el in a:
      if valid(el):
        proces(el, direct_container)
else:
  for el in a:
       proces(el, direct_container)

# ===================================
def proces(el, direct_container)
 rel = self.get_rel(el)
 if rel is None:
   add_without_rel(el)
 else:
   direct_container["32"].add(rel)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first `for` loop be `for el in a:`? The comment above says "a has elements"

Comment: Do you want `proces` to return another defaultdict (without mutating the passed-in one), or a plain dict?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - yes, thanks I changed the code

Comment: @slothrop yes I want to avoid mutation of an argument  in an external function. The code can be rewritten is not necessary to use process as it is

Comment: So in the `process` function, rather than adding to `direct_container`, you could create a new dictionary with the extra item. If you want a one-liner: `return deepcopy(direct_container) | {"32": direct_container["32"] | {rel}}`. If you're happy with more lines of (simpler) code then you could just deepcopy the default dict, do your current .add operation, and return the modified copy.